# how to hide div/element when you scroll pass it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to hide two divs with the height 100vh when you scroll past them but so far it just hides the first div.

My HTML:

```
<div id="bluevh">My Height is 100vh</div>
<div id="vh">My Height is 100vh</div>

<h1 id="verschwinden">verschwinden</h1>
```

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var $nav = $('#verschwinden'),
        $win = $(window),
        winH = $win.height() * 2;    // Get the window height.

    $win.on("scroll", function () {
       $nav.toggleClass("doch", $(this).scrollTop() > winH );
       $('#bluevh').css('display', 'none');
       $('#vh').css('display', 'none');

    }).on("resize", function(){ // If the user resizes the window
       winH = $(this).height(); // you'll need the new height value
    });

});
```

The jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4zw0cjsu/141/

Comment: Do you have to use this JQuery function? Or can it be another JQuery function that fades the two divs when user scrolls past them?

Comment: @billy.farroll you don't need to use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two divs to fade when the user scrolls down the page. You could use this **JQuery** function:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="bluevh">My Height is 100vh</div>
<div class="vh">My Height is 100vh</div>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    $(".bluevh, .vh").css("opacity", 1 - 
        $(window).scrollTop() / 300); 
});
```

Comment: One second. I'll provide a accurate snippet for you.